# Django Queryset - get related objects

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I would like to get the related objects of each object in a queryset.

**Example:**

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
from django.db import models


class Synonym:
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    entry_object = GenericForeignKey('entry_type', 'entry_id')

class Name:
    synonyms = GenericRelation(Synonym, object_id_field='entry_id', content_type_field='entry_type')    

names = Name.objects.all()
synonyms = names.values_list('synonyms', flat=True)  # <- returns the database id but not the object
```

But the value_list method returns only the id of the objects within the queryset.

I could flatten the output propably like this:

```
[synonym for name in list(names) for synonym in name.synonyms.all()]
```

**But I wondered if there is a way to directly get the objects?**

Comment: Do you have a `GenericForeignKey`? If yes can you add it to the question?

Comment: @GerritGeeraerts thanks for your question, I added it to the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a value for the [**`related_query_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation.related_query_name):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation


class Name(models.Model):
    synonyms = GenericRelation(Synonym, related_query_name='name')
```

You can then fetch items in reverse, for example with:

```
Synonym.objects.filter(name__isnull=False).distinct()
```

will fetch all `Synonym`s with a related `Name` object, whereas for example:

```
Synonym.objects.filter(name__value__startswith='a').distinct()
```

will retrieve all `Synonym`s for which there is a related `Name` object where the `value` starts with `'a'`.

Answer (score 1):

What you already listed here is correct

```
qs = Name.objects.all()
[synonym for synonyms in list(qs) for synonym in synonyms]
```

But can be (Maybe) opitimized with (Need testing):

```
qs = Name.objects.all()
synonyms = []
for obj in qs:
    synonyms.extend(obj.synonyms.all())
```